# Benutzung von „es“ im Satz: „Das Ziel ist es, …“

Tags: usage, style, expletiva

> Das Ziel ist **es**, etwas zu tun.

Soll bei dieser Formulierung »es« verwendet werden? Und wenn ja, warum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Das Ziel ist, etwas zu tun.
>
> Etwas zu tun(,) ist das Ziel.

Wie du anhand dieser beiden Varianten sehen kannst, ist das *es* nicht notwendig. Es ist aber auch nicht falsch. Es verweist quasi schon einmal auf den folgenden Infinitiv, und trennt ihn dadurch – meines Erachtens – etwas stärker vom Restsatz ab.

Grammatikalisch würde ich den Infinitiv als Subjekt sehen wollen, denn dieser wird als *das Ziel* definiert. (Das ist nicht immer eindeutig.) Es ist allerdings nicht immer schön, einen Infinitiv als Subjekt zu haben, (sic!) weswegen dieser durch das Expletativ *es* vorweggenommen werden kann. Übrigens kann man auch deinen Satz so umformlieren, dass das *es* vorne steht:

> Es ist das Ziel, etwas zu tun.

Answer (score 2):

**The additional "*es*" emphasizes a little bit what to follow.** You *can* use it to put more weight on the infinitive.

---

**Side note:** You don't necessarily need a comma if you are not using "*es*" (because the infinitive entity takes over the function of an object in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Grammatikalisch richtig ist all das:

> Das Ziel ist es, etwas zu tun.
>
> Das Ziel ist, etwas zu tun.
>
> Ziel ist es, etwas zu tun.
>
> Ziel ist, etwas zu tun.

Die Satzaussage ist immer die gleiche, wobei es aber eher selten vorkommt, ein Tun, eine Handlung als Ziel festzulegen. Ein Ziel ist (nicht immer, aber in der Regel) ein Zustand, und die Handlung das, was zum Ziel führt.